# DB2: FAILED: CDIPR2123I: Ensure that the database xmeta is empty

Tags: db2, websphere, ibm-infosphere

I am installing InfoSphere V1171 on Linux RHEL 7.

When I am trying to install InfoSphere but in the validation step I get the error:

```
FAILED: CDIPR2123I: Ensure that the database xmeta is empty
```

I have tried to drop the table using the below command and recreate the DB but the error reappears:

```
db2 drop database xmeta
```

How can I clear the DB?

Comment: please edit your question to add facts. What is the __full__ product name? What is the exact version?  What operating system are you installing on? Which documentation URL are you following for this administration/configuration question?

Comment: hi @mao, i add the info. InfoSphere V1171 on Linux RHEL 7

Comment: IBM Infosphere is a brand (not a product), with different products offered in that brand. Do you mean Infosphere Datastage (Infosphere Information Server) ?  Can you please edit the question to show the URL of the instructions you are following?